# $dH_x(v) = dF_x(v)G(x)+F(x)dG_x(v)$

Tags: differential-geometry, matrix-calculus

Let $F : M \to \mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$ (where $\mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$ are $m\times k$ matrices with real coefficients)  and $G : M \to \mathbb{R}^{k\times n}$.

Define $H : M \to \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ by $H(x)=F(x)G(x)$. I want to show that $dH_x(v) = dF_x(v)G(x)+F(x)dG_x(v)$ but I am not sure how to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$ then the chain rule said that
$$
dH_x(v)=(H\circ \gamma)'(0)
$$

but $H\circ \gamma$ it's now a curve on $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ given by
$$
F(\gamma(t))G(\gamma(t))
$$.
if $F=(F_{ij})$ and $G=(G_{ij})$ then
$$
(H\circ \gamma(t))_{ij}=\sum_{k}F_{ik}(\gamma(t))G_{kj}(\gamma(t))
$$
then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(H\circ \gamma(t))_{ij}=\sum_{k}\frac{d}{dt}(F_{ik}(\gamma(t)))G_{kj}(\gamma(t))+\sum_{k}F_{ik}(\gamma(t))\frac{d}{dt}(G_{kj}(\gamma(t)))
$$

by the chain rule on $\mathbb{R}$, thus
$$
\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(H\circ \gamma(t))_{ij}=\sum_k d(F_{ik})_x(v)G_{kj}(x)+\sum_k F_{ik}(x)d(G_{kj})_x(v)
$$

thus
$$
dH_x(v)=dF_x(v)G(x)+F(x)dG_x(v)
$$

Comment: thank you! This is very helpful